# What is 'humbling thought'?

Tags: word-meaning

I was reading this [news article.](https://www.womenshealthmag.com/health/a33414781/florida-tv-reporter-victoria-price-thyroid-cancer/?utm_campaign=socialflowTWWH&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social-media) And this paragraph is a part of the article:

> Hi, just saw your news report. What concerned me is the lump on your
> neck. Please have your thyroid checked. Reminds me of my neck. Mine
> turned out to be cancer. Take care of yourself."
>
> Price got the lump
> checked out, and sure enough, she was diagnosed with thyroid cancer.
>
> Had I never received that email, I never would have called my doctor.
> The cancer would have continued to spread. It's a scary and **humbling
> thought**," Price wrote. "I will forever be grateful to the woman who
> went out of her way to email me, a total stranger. She had zero
> obligation to, but she did anyway. Talk about being on your side, huh?

I know the meaning of 'humble' as showing an attitude of not being proud. But the meaning doesn't seem fit with the sentence.

The word is used with 'scary' so I guess it might have a similar meaning as scary. But does the humble have the meaning of 'scary'?

Comment: See [this definition of "humbling"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humbling). It is scary because the cancer would have spread if left unchecked, and humbling perhaps because the person's physical health now seems more vulnerable, or because they were helped by a stranger. Either of these possibilities could potentially lessen a person's pride.

Comment: @Wehage I don't quite understand why she has to feel losing pride. It's nothing to be ashamed of. It is a natural thing to have the disease. It's not her fault. I never say in this way with my native language and I feel a bit weird.

Comment: It doesn't mean that it is anything to be ashamed of. The link provided by @Wehage speaks of 'feeling less important or special than you thought'. She realised that, although she was a TV personality,  she was just another victim of cancer, who could have become seriously ill if this person hadn't taken the trouble to warn her.